# Unable to download images from GitHub repositories

Tags: javascript, git, github, npm

I am currently experiencing an issue where I am unable to download images from GitHub repositories. Whenever I try to download an image by right-clicking and selecting "Save Image As" or using the "Download" button provided by GitHub, the image file is not downloaded.
Additional information:

I have tried this issue on different web browsers (e.g., Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox) but encountered the same problem.
Clearing browser cache and cookies did not resolve the issue.
I have also tried downloading images from different GitHub repositories, but the problem persists.
This issue started occurring recently. I was able to download images from GitHub repositories without any issues before.
Please let me know if there is any workaround or solution for this problem.

Steps to reproduce:

Go to any GitHub repository containing images.
Attempt to download an image by right-clicking on the image and selecting "Save Image As" or using the "Download" button provided by GitHub.
Observe that the image file is not downloaded, or the downloaded file appears to be corrupted.
Expected behavior:
The image file should be downloaded successfully and be accessible for use.

Actual behavior:
The image file is not downloaded, or the downloaded file appears to be corrupted.

Comment: You should instead reach GitHub's support.